# MacBook Air 2014: when I boot with SDcard "SDXC", the mouse does not work. However, when booting via USB stick, there are no problems on the same HW

Tags: tails, linux

I use latest Tails with persistent LUKS volume. My hardware is [MacBook Air 2014](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp700?locale=en_US) (running Debian as daily driver; the machine is well supported).

When I boot with SDcard "SanDisk SDXC" (there is an internal reader), the mouse does not work. However, boot via USB stick there are no problems on the same hardware.

I do not want to boot Tails via USB stick, but with SDcard "SanDisk SDXC". Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It's a Tails's buggy old kernel: no HW issue here, same things happening with USB wifi dongles... Tails is immature till this moment regardless of the time it exists. Use [QubesOS](https://www.qubes-os.org/) - it's based on Xen and has a very mature and secure insulation environment. Tor can be runned on a routing VM in a headless mode - so you will wrap **all** the slave machines **and** apps securely through it